Resolving File Corruption in Python Script for Removing Embedded Audio from PowerPoint Presentations
When attempting to use a Python script to remove audio files embedded in PowerPoint (.pptx) presentations, the script sometimes corrupts the .pptx files instead of cleanly removing the audio content. The script is designed to:Rename the .pptx file to a .zip extension to manipulate its contents as a zip archive.Extract the contents of this zip file to a temporary directory.Identify and delete audio files from the 'media' folder within the extracted contents.Search through the extracted files for relationship (.rels) files and remove references to the deleted audio files to prevent broken links within the presentation.Repackage the modified contents into a new zip file and rename it back to a .pptx extension.The expected outcome is a .pptx file without the audio files, retaining all other content and functionalities intact. However, the script not only fails to achieve this consistently but also sometimes results in corrupted .pptx files that cannot be opened or have lost significant content beyond the intended removal of audio files.
import os
import zipfile
import shutil
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

def remove_audio_references_from_rels(rels_file, audio_files):
    # Note que audio_files aqui é uma lista dos nomes dos arquivos de áudio
    tree = ET.parse(rels_file)
    root = tree.getroot()
    namespaces = {'': 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships'}

    # Identifique as relações que apontam para arquivos de áudio e remova-as
    for relationship in root.findall('Relationship', namespaces):
        target = relationship.attrib.get('Target', '')
        if any(audio_file in target for audio_file in audio_files):
            root.remove(relationship)
    
    tree.write(rels_file)

def process_pptx(pptx_file):
    audio_extensions = ('.aiff', '.au', '.mid', '.midi', '.mp3', '.m4a', '.mp4', '.wav', '.wma')
    base = os.path.splitext(pptx_file)[0]
    temp_dir = os.path.join(init_dir, base + '_temp')
    new_zip = base + '.zip'

    # Renomeia o pptx para zip e extrai
    os.rename(pptx_file, new_zip)
    with zipfile.ZipFile(new_zip) as myzip:
        myzip.extractall(temp_dir)
    
    # Identifica e remove os arquivos de áudio
    audio_files = [file for file in os.listdir(os.path.join(temp_dir, 'ppt', 'media')) if file.endswith(audio_extensions)]
    for audio_file in audio_files:
        os.remove(os.path.join(temp_dir, 'ppt', 'media', audio_file))

    # Percorre os arquivos .rels para remover as referências aos arquivos de áudio removidos
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(temp_dir):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith('.rels'):
                remove_audio_references_from_rels(os.path.join(root, file), audio_files)
    
    # Recria o arquivo pptx
    with zipfile.ZipFile(new_zip, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as myzip:
        for folder, _, files in os.walk(temp_dir):
            for file in files:
                absolute_path = os.path.join(folder, file)
                relative_path = os.path.relpath(absolute_path, temp_dir)
                myzip.write(absolute_path, relative_path)
    
    shutil.rmtree(temp_dir)
    os.rename(new_zip, pptx_file)

print('Starting modification process...')
init_dir = os.getcwd()
pptx_files = [file for file in os.listdir() if file.endswith('.pptx')]

for pptx_file in pptx_files:
    print(f'\nProcessing file: {pptx_file}')
    process_pptx(pptx_file)

print('\nModification complete.')




Just a guess, but is it possible that animation settings/transition settings refer to the audio files in some way? If they're not reset, they could be left pointing at resources that no longer exist. It'd be worth creating a simple test file that reliably corrupts using your method. Keep the corrupted version and also open the original, manually remove the audio. Save it, then unzip both and compare the results. That might point you at a solution.

Once renamed into .zip, it would be best NOT to extract the files, but work on those inside the archive. They will not be corrupted in this way.
